# How do I create list of unique records from a MySQL table, and then use those records to calculate means

Tags: mysql

I have a big MySQL table called rent_suburbs that has columns like:

bed, bath, type, suburb, postcode, price

What is the best way to create a list of unique records from this table (eg 2 bedroom, 2 bathroom, apartment in Cliffton Hill, 3068) and then query the table to return a value for the average price for this particular type and location of property?

I have tried

```
select avg(price) from rent_suburbs group by bed, bath, type, suburb, postcode
```

but it returns error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'price' in 'field list' even though price is definitely a column.  Please give me a suggestion and save me from hours of blind trial and error.

Thanks ~ Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better have a look into [***MySQL GROUP BY***](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx)

```
select bed, bath, type, suburb, postcode,avg(price) 
from rent_suburbs group by bed, bath, type, suburb, postcode
```